# Question regarding Sweden's privacy laws and renting a dedicated server in Stockholm

Tags: privacy, sweden

I am from the United States. If I rent a dedicated server in Sweden and for some reason the server would need to be accessed by U.S. authorities, can the U.S. simply force me to give up my SSH access key or are they subject to Sweden's privacy laws?

Thank you,
Tim